# Anylogic: adjust number of visitors over time (with trend?)

Tags: simulation, anylogic, trend

I am trying to create a trend in which visitors to an event slowly decline every year.
This is the setup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETZo1.jpg
I want to ensure that for instance in year 1 there are 100,000 visitors but the next year this declines with 1%, so that next year only 99,000 visitors are present and the year after that 99.000*0.99 so in the total of those years 297.010 people have visited. (So, the Stock value of visitors being 297.010 after a simulation of 3 years)
*What values/formulas should I give my NewInfoRealVisitors variable and flow equation for example? Or all the other variables for that matter*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a lot of things to do here, first your structure is wrong and should be like this:
[image: Model Structure]

visitorsPerYear = annualVisitors   it's the same variable, but defined as a flow and as a stock at the same time

annualVisitorsDecline = annualVisitors*declineRate

Now, to obtain the exact values you want (total visitors = 297010)
you need to use years as the model time units and you need to use 1 as the fixed time step:
[image]

And finally, you need to run the model in virtual time (as fast as possible) because otherwise anylogic changes your fixed time step without your control
[image]

If you don't do all this, you will just get an approximation of 297.010 based on Euler equations... close enough, but not exactly it.

Comment: First of all, thank you for all the effort! Second of all, I am so close! I have done everything you said but can't find the Tolerances screenshot you showed. My final value for annual visitors is 295,546.12. I am thinking that if I find those tolerance settings it should give me the proper values? :)

Comment: you find that in your model properties, where you define the model time units... just click on the name of your model, which is over everything